# XML file generated by a SOAP API callout

Tags: integration, xml

I developed an API callout to a SOAP webservice, the external system return me an error, how can i see XML file generated by a SOAP API callout?

Comment: Generate same request and use SoapUI to view the error message?

Comment: the xml is generate by many function and i would see what SF sends when generate a collout. 
there is no way to see xml?

Comment: If you want to see what request salesforce sends, then you can change endpoint to RequestBin or any other mocking service. It will let u view the request sent from sf

Answer (score 2):

You can hook your request to a mocking service like https://putsreq.com/ or requestbin.

They allow you to view the raw requests.

Make sure you insert that endpoint Remote site settings as well.

Once you do that and do a callout, you can inspect it at putreq website.

[image]